# ie10 windows 8 desktop html file thinks I'm on a local intranet

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I just dragged a html file into IE10 on windows 8 non-metro interface and a browser prompter says something about local intranet.  How do I disable this from happening?

Comment: "something about local intranet" isn't very helpful. *Exactly what* is it saying about local intranet?

Comment: Actually the warning goes away but IE10 for windows 8 still won't run JavaScript from a desktop file it says something about "Active X" and there is no more dropdown to allow. However I did test on a local network the same file and the warnings go away, but a new pop says something about intanet, which I can ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security policy of IE says that local files will be treated as part of the local intranet zone, this can be changed via the security settings of IE, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/149068/how-to-add-a-local-file-to-trusted-zone-in-ie8).